# physics: monkey heads contained in a box

Tags: physics

trying to create something similar to a "molecular dynamics" simulation.  Basically a bunch of little objects bumping into each other to simulate what the inside of a biological cell looks like.   Any advice will help.

I did a test with a bunch of monkey heads inside of a box (planes).  I set the gravity to zero and built a box.   I turned on passive rigid body physics for the walls of the box.  I put on active physics for the heads.   Then I run the animation and EVERYTHING EXPLODES.   Well the heads go flying out of the box.  How can I contain the heads within an area?  The walls are useless.

Also, any idea how to get transparent shader to work with eevee?   I cant see through a transparent plane!

thanks[image]

Comment: There are a dozen ways this could be going wrong. Are the monkey collision systems set to convex hull, or mesh? Are you sure the box pieces are oriented the right way? Is the box “overstuffed” as it were?

Comment: Keep it to one question! That last bit is not only totally unrelated, it is a *very* common problem. Look up “EEVEE alpha blending” for more of an explanation, but you need to change the alpha blend method in the material’s settings in the Properties editor.

Comment: @Chris done!   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make material transparent in EEVEE, set mode to alpha blend:

[image]

Set the box rigid body -> shape -> to "mesh".

[image]

result (but with gravity):

[image]

Note: convex hull is just as you would wrap a paper tight around an object. So it is good for very easy cases like spheres or boxes if you use it at collision from outside of it. For everything else - more complex objects or objects with hole, you should use "mesh" because it really uses the geometry and not a simplified version for a better performance.

And you shouldn't write things like "the walls are useless" - could be considered as rude. You should write: what am i doing wrong that it doesn't work?

Note: another import aspect for running simulations: you should have applied scale and rotation for every object you use.

Watching beginner tutorials about rigid bodies on yt is also a big help as a beginner.

Comment: thank you!   did not mean to be rude.  Just frustrated with my knowledge.  heh.   Yes I have been digging through YT.  Hard for Blender 3 though.   

That helped and I am making progress.  I have one more issue maybe you can help with please.  I followed tutorial in link below.  I have a membrane bilayer. I have "wave" modifier on.I want to have spheres floating inside the cell.  However I cant get the cell membrane to act like a static body to reflect back the bounces.  things just go right through.   any help <3

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEmQoIxtbcQ&ab_channel=CGFigures

Comment: please open up a new question so everybody can answer it and everybody can learn from it. If i answer in comments nobody will find it. Thank you.